# angular 2 http get request getting called twice, when the size of data is large

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, rest, api

I m trying to fetch history data for one month using angular http get request. I m using angular 5,server is in node js and db is mongodb.
On first click on button it hits the server and console is printed on server. After 2 mins again server consoles as ui hits server, but there is no call made by the ui to server. After 1 min, sent successful response is showed by server, but ui console displays like error-"connection refused". i tried to resolve it using share from observable. But it did not work
This is my service.

```
getReports(params): Observable<number>{
        let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
        return this.http.get(url, options)
       .map((res: Response) => res.json())
       .catch(this.handleError)}
```

Comment: Any suggestion will be great help.

Comment: your tag says angularjs, but this is not angularjs... it's angular

Comment: you have to increase response time. By default every technology will call request again if didn't received response after certain time.

Comment: Thanks @RatanUdayKumar for your answer. How can i increase the response time in angular

Comment: update my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like below

```
return this.http.get(url, options)
    .timeout(3000, new Error('timeout exceeded'))
    .map((res: Response) => res.json())
    .subscribe(
        data => this.data = data,
        error => console.debug('ERROR', error),
        () => console.log('END')
      );
    .catch(this.handleError)}
```

using timeout it is possible. 3000 means 3 secs or 3000 ms

Comment: i updated my answer @RatanUdayKumar.  I gave response time as 120000 ie. 2 minutes. But still i can see the server is called again after 2 minutes.

Comment: in angular in client side for every api there will be 2 request but server will get only 1 request

Comment: 2 times server is getting the request.

Comment: how much time does server taking to send response

Comment: Once i send the request i can see in console like fetching by date range, after 2 minutes again the same console is appearing. And after 1 min it shows sent succesfull response. But by that time browser shows error-"connection refused" or connection timed out

Comment: it will prompt error message but it not call server

Comment: request will not send to server

Comment: using morgan dependency in nodejs you can see all http request of nodejs

Comment: Thanks. ll check it